# strange break (white) lines presenting in the columns and rows of the heatmap in R

Tags: r

this problem confuses me for a long time
I use pheatmap to draw a 10000* 2000(more or less) size matrix , final plot will show some blank(white) lines inserting to the row and col of my main plot in most of the time, like some cut-off rules to my main plot.
I have checked my data , it has no NA rows or cols. And this cut-off lines will change position when adjusting the resolution of the plot. wheather ploting directly in Rstudio window or generating the plot file in work path, this problem can not be avoided either.

I guess this problem may due to the graphic system of R or the resolution or anti-aliasing settings, if someone can solve this, I would appreciate it greatfully.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: I think you've hit the nail on the head with the resolution of the plot. If your plot has about as many data elements across as it has pixels, it will produce artifacts like that at various resolutions. I'd suggest saving the plot to disk at a very high resolution and using a dedicated image viewing program to look at it. In general, realize that the representation of data on your screen is limited by the resolution of your monitor.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: this seems quite sound , I will try it later,  thank you very much for such a quick comment!  this is the first time that I use stack overflow to submit a question, what a amazing experience ！